# Take snapshot of web page with WebView control (WPF or UWP)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, uwp

I need to take a snapshot of a web page that uses JS Service Worker rendered with **EdgeHTML (Spartan) view engine**, which is available through WebView 1 control, in WPF and UWP.

Issue I have when WebView is used in WPF: don't know how to take a screenshot. If I use RenderTargetBitmap and something like (added namespace, because there are multiple RenderTargetBitmaps):

```
var bmp = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.RenderTargetBitmap(1000, 1000, 72, 72, PixelFormats.Default);
bmp.Render(webView1);
var frame = System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame.Create(bmp);
var encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Frames.Add(frame);
using (var stream = File.Create("fooo.jpg"))
{
    encoder.Save(stream);
}
```

it just renders and saves black frame.

In UWP I can actually take a snapshot and save it into the file, because WebView has method for that:

```
var pics = KnownFolders.SavedPictures;
var file = await pics.CreateFileAsync("foo.jpg");
using (var fileStream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
{
    var ras = fileStream.AsRandomAccessStream();
    await webView1.CapturePreviewToStreamAsync(ras);
}
```

But the problem here is that page I have to render is using **ServiceWorker** for some API mocking, and in UWP app service worked doesn't work, compared to WPF where it works fine!
Can't figure out why Service Worker doesn't get registered in UWP embedded browser.

Apparently, WebView control, even it wraps the same legacy Edge engine, is quite different in WPF compared to UWP.

https://www.whatismybrowser.com/ shows the same, correct, browser (Edge 18, EdgeHTML view engine) from both WPF and UWP.

The questions are:

- how to save a snapshot in WPF, or
- how to enable Service Worker in UWP

Comment: @andy Webview v1 is EdgeHTML, Webview v2 is chromium Edge, and WebBrowser is Internet Explorer (Trident i think)

Comment: Good point.  He does say "webview" several times. But yep.

Comment: May I know what is `ServiceWorker` that you mentioned?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT this lib https://mswjs.io/, but in IE dev tools I see Service Worker is not attached/registered when using WebView in UWP, and it is in WPF.